# right join in sql is not giving answers as expected

Tags: mysql

As per right join, I am not getting the whole data set from the right table(Table_B). Please help with this code and correct me if I have done some mistake. Following are the tables:

TABLE_A:

```
Age Address eName   City
A1  AD1     N1      C1
A3  AD3     N3      C3
A5  AD5     N5      C5
A7  AD7     N7      C7
A9  AD9     N9      C9
```

TABLE_B:

```
City    eName
C2      N2
C4      N4
C6      N6
C8      N8
C9      N9
C10     N10




select table_a.ename,table_a.age, table_a.address, table_b.city 
from table_a right join table_b on table_b.eName=table_a.eName;
```

Output:

```
ename   age    address  city
N9      A9      AD9     C9
NULL    NULL    NULL    C2
NULL    NULL    NULL    C4
NULL    NULL    NULL    C6
NULL    NULL    NULL    C8
NULL    NULL    NULL    C10
```

Comment: You are getting the correct result.

Comment: What Did you expect for a result?

Comment: "I'm not getting the whole data set from the right table". Yes, you ere. There are 6 rows in Table B, and 6 rows in the result.

Comment: Incidentally, nobody ever uses right join

Comment: we could include `table_b.ename` in the SELECT list, to return both `city` and `ename` columns, as an attempt to satisfy the specification to return "whole data set from the right table". One way to think about the outer join:  when no matching row is found in table_a, mysql generates a *dummy* row as if it was from table_a, to serve as a matching row.. The generated dummy row consists of all NULL values. Echoing previous comments, the result set returned appears to be exactly waht we expect the example query to return.

Answer (score 0):

if your requirement to get all records of table_b and base on table_b will get table_a.
I think that you can write query like below

```
SELECT table_b.ename,table_b.city, table_a.age, table_a.address
FROM table_b 
LEFT JOIN table_a 
   ON table_a.eName=table_b.eName;
```